# Find integer not occurring twice in an array

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem:
In an integer array all numbers occur exactly twice, except for a single number which occurs exactly once.

A simple solution is to sort the array and then test for non repetition. But I am looking for  better solution that has time complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use "xor" operation on the entire array. Each pair of numbers will cancel each other, leaving you with the sought value.

```
int get_orphan(int const * a, int len)
{
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        value ^= a[i];

    // `value` now contains the number that occurred odd number of times.
    // Retrieve its index in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] == value)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: oh that dint strike me. Great!

Comment: How is this not `O(n)`? What do you think the complexity is?

Comment: How to handle even more then 1 orphan??

Comment: @Noli, with difficulties I'm afraid. I doubt there's an `O(n)` solution.