# How to find uncoupled integer in an array?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find integer not occurring twice in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168716/find-integer-not-occurring-twice-in-an-array)
>   [Accenture interview question - find the only unpaired element in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644179/accenture-interview-question-find-the-only-unpaired-element-in-the-array)

Given an array of integers of odd size. All the integers in the array appear twice except for a single integer. How to find this uncoupled integer in most efficient (both memory and complexity-wise) way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you XOR all of them together, you'll end up with the lone (uncoupled) value.

That's because `x` XOR `x` is zero for all `x` values, and `0` XOR `x` is `x`.

By way of example, the following program outputs `99`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int num[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    unsigned int i;
    int accum;

    for (accum = 0, i = 0; i < sizeof(num)/sizeof(*num); i++)
        accum ^= num[i];

    printf ("%d\n", accum);

    return 0;
}
```

In terms of efficiency, it's basically O(1) space and O(n) time complexity, minimal, average and worst case.

Comment: @Guarav, then you'll get zero, as expected. Try it. Change the 99 in the above code and let 'er rip :-)

Answer (score 1):

As pax suggests, XOR'ing all the elements together will give you your lone value.

```
int getUncoupled(int *values, int len)
{
    int uncoupled = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        uncoupled ^= values[i];
    return uncoupled;
}
```

However there is a slight caveat here: What's the difference between no uncoupled values and a set whose uncoupled value is zero? `x^x^y^y = 0` but doesn't `x^x^0^y^y` also equal zero? Food for thought :)

Comment: There's no difference in the output but, given that the specs "odd size" and "all the integers in the array appear twice except for a single integer", `x^x^y^y` is impossible.

Comment: My mistake, I more meant if the array wasn't odd-sized. Given that it's a question constraint, I guess me pointing that out was irrelevant.